# Twython rate limit

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am getting a 'TwythonRateLimitError' and want to be sure that I don't screw up my account.  I am new to working with the Twitter API.  How can I check to make sure that I am not going over my query limit?  I read that it is 150 queries/hour... What happens if I do? Am I at a risk of this in my code or is it only for particular commands?

I am not building an app, I am just trying to get a specific sample for twitter (random set of users with similar following bases (7500 to 10000 followers).  My code so far is below. I will be saving the successful hits to a file but I am waiting to be sure that is necessary.

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError, TwythonRateLimitError
from random import randint

APP_KEY = 'redacted'
APP_SECRET = 'redacted'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'redacted'

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, oauth_version=2)
ACCESS_TOKEN = twitter.obtain_access_token()

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY,access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN)

print "hello twitterQuery\n"

count = 0
step = 0
isError = 0
try:
    #new account i made today to set upper bound on userID
    maxID = twitter.show_user(screen_name="query_test")['id']
except TwythonRateLimitError:
    isError = 1
ids = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
if isError == 0 and step <= 150:
    while count < 10:
        step = step +1
        randomID = randint(1,maxID)
        isMissing = 0
        print str(step) + " " + str(randomID)
        try:
            randomUserData = twitter.show_user(user_id=randomID)
        except TwythonError:
            isMissing = 1;
        if isMissing == 0:
            followers = randomUserData['followers_count']
            if followers >= 7500 and followers <= 10000:
                print "ID: " + str(randomID) +", followers: "+ str(followers)
                ids[count] = randomID
                count = count+1

print "\ndone"
for each id in ids:
    print id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to see your current rate limit status, pass in your app token and send a GET request to

[https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/rate_limit_status.json](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/application/rate_limit_status)

and query the response.

See [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1) for further context

Comment: I looked into this and am not sure if I understand.  Does that mean I can query any user up to 15 times? I ran this in the Twitter dev console and it went from 15 to 14, then I ran my application and ran it in the console again and expected it to -1 for each query but it didnt actually go down at all.  Is this because I only queried my dev username once? But if I run it enough it will reference the "query_user" account 15 times and use up the attempts?

Comment: it's probably caching your requests.